# 外部へのリンクしかない回答にはどう対応するべき？

Tags: 討議

たまに、外部へのリンクしか情報量がない回答を見かけます。このような回答に対して、取るべき行動は何ですか？

特に、削除票を投じるべきかしないべきかが、個人的に判断に迷っているところです。

Comment: http://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/30518/754 を見ていて、この質問を作成するに至ったのですが、 http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers によれば、「外部サイトへの単なるリンク」は削除対象ですね。例えそれが、その質問に対して答える形で回答者本人によって記述されていたのだとしても、だったら第３者サイトでそのような記事を見つけた場合と何が違うのかと言われれば、何も違わないはず。割と自己解決しました。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

基本的には Stack Overflow で期待される形式ではありませんから、削除対象かと思います。
（削除ではなく、「コメント化」のような操作に投票が出来ればいいのですが）

しかし、日本語版の現状を見るに、リンク先に回答として有効なコンテンツがあるならば、当分こういった回答もありがたい状況なのではないかとも思いますので、私は積極的に削除投票はしません。
現に、[例として出されている質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/29828/3054)においては、今のところ他の回答がなく、件の回答を削除する事に、何のメリットもない状況だと思います。

---

また、以下のような場合は、例外になると思います。

- URL 自体が完全な回答である場合。
  例えば「XX の公式ドキュメントはどこにありますか？」「XX が可能なライブラリを探しています」といった質問です。
  これは、URL が回答として十分な物になります。
- 回答に Stack Overflow で書き切れないような内容が必要で、それがリンク先にある場合。
  広範囲に渡る質問などは、こういった回答にならざるを得ないと思います。
  質問が悪い可能性が高いので、質問はクローズ対象になるかも知れませんが。

---

追記:

> 清‌​書を促すか、反応が無いなら拾い上げて清書‌​後、削除投票もありなのではないかな？と思‌​いましたがどうでしょう？
>   （Myaku さんのコメントより）

そうあるべきだとは思うのですが、一般的なユーザがこれを受け入れるかが、私には分かりません。
「回答を盗られた」と解釈される可能性もあります。
サイトを去っていく人は意見を残しませんから、残った者たちだけで議論せざるを得ず、色々と先鋭化してしまうのが心配です。

Comment: >>`今のところ他の回答がなく、件の回答を削除する事に、何のメリットもない`、確かにそうなのですが、リンクが生きているなら清書を促すか、反応が無いなら拾い上げて清書後、削除投票もありなのではないかな？と思いましたがどうでしょう？